# atan2() in gcc strange behavior, w_atan2.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, atan2

I have included in my code the math.h and also used -lm but when i use the gcc debugger when it comes to atan2() i get the following:

```
16      result = atan2(x,y) * val;

(gdb) 

__atan2 (y=15, x=32) at w_atan2.c:31
31  w_atan2.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 

34  in w_atan2.c

(gdb) 

__ieee754_atan2_sse2 (y=15, x=32) at ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_atan2.c:92
```

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265


main(){

    double x, y, val, result;

    val = 180 / PI;
    x = 15;
    y = 32;

    result = atan2(x,y) * val;
    printf("%lf\n",result);

}
```

Comment: Am I correct that you only have a problem in the debugger?

Comment: @user3114046 it compiles and runs correctly also for me, but i have a bigger code where i use atan2() and atan2() does not behave as expected, so when i use gdb debugger i get what i posted, i tested atan2() in this smaller code and i get these messages from debugger even it compiles and runs fine

Comment: @user3114046 the variable result gives me degrees

Comment: Note: The order of parameters is `y` then `x` in `double atan2(double y, double x);`

Comment: @chux yes i know, that's not my problem

Comment: @user3114046 that's strange, my debugger keeps giving me those messages when it comes to execute the atan2() even though the code executes fine out of debugger. Do i have to set a path for math.h or something?

Comment: even if i use cos(x) debugger gives me: __get_cpu_features () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/init-arch.c:180
180 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/init-arch.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: I don't get the error if I just type `run` into gdb, but if I step through the code 1 line at a time I get something very similar: w_atan2.c: No such file or directory. Weird.

Comment: @user3114046 exactly, i step the code and i get this. In this small code there is no problem, but i use it in a big code and i can't find what is wrong with it. Is there any way i can find arctan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can figure it out, by typing `step` into the debugger before the line `result = atan2(x,y) * val;` you're telling gdb to step into the `atan2` function which will not work if you don't have the sources. You probably don't need to debug `atan2` so `next` is probably the command you want.

If you continue stepping after that you'll encounter a similar error when you hit printf, because you also can't step into that. If you really wanted to get into running the debugger on the library functions, there is some discussion here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1374829

Comment: thank you, that helped me to debug and find what was wrong in my code. So from now on i use next ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this...

long double ATAN2(long double Y, long double X)
{
        register long double VALUE;

```
    __asm__ __volatile__("fpatan\n\t": "=t" (VALUE) : "0" (X), "u" (Y) : "st(1)");
    return VALUE;
```

}

hope this helps and by the way have a look inside the Mathinline.h and you will able to write your Math functions which should be smaller. also here is atan...

long double ATAN(long double RADIANS)
{
        register long double RESULT;

```
    __asm__ __volatile__("fld1\n\t" "fpatan\n\t": "=t" (RESULT) : "0" (RADIANS) : "st(1)");
    return RESULT;
```

}